# Calling method at the end of sprite animation in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone

Can anybody tell me how to call a method at the end of the sprite animation.
I want the last image to be removed from the scene. Thats why i want to call that method.
If there is any better way to do that please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the end of your CCSequence:

```
CCCallFuncO* removeMe = [CCCallFuncO actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeMe:) object:variableOfObjectToRemove];
```

Then:

```
- (void) removeMe:(id)object {
//remove
}
```

Comment: While the removeMe method is straight-Apple. If you KNOW the only objects you'll send to removeMe are of a certain type, you can replace id with your class and skip having to typecast object.